# Gulp: Add srcset property to all img tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, gulp

I'm building a site using `gulp` and `jekyll` and I am trying to setup the gulpfile so that it will automatically go through all of the `html` files and add `srcset` information for responsive image delivery.

Basically, I want to turn this:

```
<img src="/img/agency/agency-lobby.jpg" />
```

Into this (for every image in HTML files):

```
<img src="/img/agency/agency-lobby.jpg" srcset="/img/agency/agency-lobby400.jpg 400w, /img/agency/agency-lobby600.jpg 600w, /img/agency/agency-lobby900.jpg 900w, /img/agency/agency-lobby900.jpg 1200w, /img/agency/agency-lobby1800.jpg 1800w"/>
```

My gulpfile is obviously configured to do a number of automated tasks, one of which is to look in the folder **unsized-img** and create image sizes for each of the breakpoints I have setup, then output that to the **img** folder *(I do this to avoid Jekyll overwriting my **_sites/img** folder with just the original images)*. Then I have an optimize task that will optimize all those images for final output in the **_sites/img** folder.

Now I want to have gulp go through and find all the img tags, and automate it so that it will add the `srcset` properties for each image, this way I don't have to manually write every single image with 5 `srcset` properties every time.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var prefix      = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var cp          = require('child_process');
var cleanCSS    = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify      = require('gulp-uglify');
var pump        = require('pump');
var imagemin    = require('gulp-imagemin');
var imageresize = require('gulp-image-resize');
var rename      = require("gulp-rename");

var jekyll   = process.platform === 'win32' ? 'jekyll.bat' : 'jekyll';
var messages = {
    jekyllBuild: '<span style="color: grey">Running:</span> $ jekyll build'
};

/**
 * Build the Jekyll Site
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);
    return cp.spawn( jekyll , ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
        .on('close', done);
});

/**
 * Rebuild Jekyll & do page reload
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-rebuild', ['jekyll-build'], function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

/**
 * Wait for jekyll-build, then launch the Server
 */
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['sass', 'jekyll-build'], function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: '_site'
        }
    });
});

/**
 * Compile files from _scss into both _site/css (for live injecting) and site (for future jekyll builds)
 */
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('_scss/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: ['scss'],
            onError: browserSync.notify
        }))
        .pipe(prefix(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true }))
        .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

/**
 * Minify javascript files (must be run separatly after gulp)
 */
gulp.task('compress', function(cb){
  pump([
        gulp.src('js/*.js'),
        uglify(),
        gulp.dest('_site/js')
    ],
    cb
  );
});

/**
 * Compress image files
 */

   var resizeImageTasks = [];
   [400,600,900,1200,1800].forEach(function(size) {
     var resizeImageTask = 'resize_' + size;
     gulp.task(resizeImageTask, function() {
         gulp.src('unsized-img/**/*.{jpg,png,gif}')
             .pipe(imageresize({
               width: size,
               upscale: false,
             }))
             .pipe(rename(function (path) { path.basename += size; }))
             .pipe(gulp.dest('img'));
           gulp.src('img/**/*.{svg,ico}')
            .pipe(gulp.dest('img'));
     });
     resizeImageTasks.push(resizeImageTask);
   });

gulp.task('resize', resizeImageTasks);

gulp.task('optimize', function() {
    gulp.src('img/**/*.{jpg,png,gif}')
        .pipe(imageresize({
          quality: 0.8,
          samplingFactor: [2, 2],
          noProfile: true,
          interlace: true,
        }))
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/img'));
      gulp.src('img/**/*.{svg,ico}')
       .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/img'));
});
/**
 * Watch scss files for changes & recompile
 * Watch html/md files, run jekyll & reload BrowserSync
 */
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('_scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['*.html', '_layouts/*.html', '_posts/*', 'work/*.html', 'services/*.html', 'culture/*.html', 'blog/*.html', 'contact/*.html', 'agency/*.html', 'blog/**/*.md','work/**/*.md'], ['jekyll-rebuild']);
});

/**
 * Default task, running just `gulp` will compile the sass,
 * compile the jekyll site, launch BrowserSync & watch files.
 */
gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: @Rob It is true that an image tag doesn't require to be closed in HTML. Adding the closing slash was a habit I developed as XHTML does require an image tag to be closed, so I always wrote my tags in that manner since it doesn't break anything in HTML by doing so, and I wouldn't have to worry about missing it should I write XHTML. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: Yes but you aren't writing XHTML and I'm betting you never will. As it stands, it becomes "tag soup" and only takes up space as it means nothing, does nothing, and browsers are instructed to ignore it which makes it useless and pointless. I'm not trying to jump on you about this. I often make this comment because many people, usually new to this, pick up on those tags as if they are a requirement.

Comment: You make an extremely good point. And yes it has been a LONG time since I've written XHTML. At the time of writing this code I was using Atom as my code editor and had a package installed that auto closed HTML tags for me (such as h2, div, etc.). I hadn't even noticed that it was also auto closing my <img> tags with a forward slash. I've since moved to Visual Studio Code and no longer have to deal with that concern it seems. While it may have very little if any impact, I'm glad you brought it up as writing proper markup is a good thing to practice.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you might be after the gulp plugin gulp-srcset-lazy (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-srcset-lazy) which is apparently a clone of the now inactive gulp-img-retina plugin.

It processes the stream, inserts the srcset attr to all image tags (note it currently ignores SVG), and uses the options to work out which resolutions or widths to add and the suffixes to apply.

In your case, I'm not sure how the Jekyll build works but I would assume you could pre-process your HTML before sending it to the build process.

```
import srcset from 'gulp-srcset-lazy';  

let srcSetOpts = {
    suffix: {
        '480w': '@480w.jpeg',
        '960w': '@960w.jpeg',
        '1440w': '@1440w.jpeg',
        '1920w': '@1920w.jpeg',
     }
};

gulp.src(inputPath)
    .pipe( srcset(srcSetOpts ) )
    .pipe( gulp.dest(outputPath) )
    .pipe( connect.reload() );
```

converts

```
<img src="images/title_bg.jpeg" alt="title background" 
    loading=lazy>
```

into

```
<img alt="title background" loading="lazy" data-format=".jpeg" 
    data-src="images/title_bg.jpeg" 
    data-srcset="images/title_bg@480w.jpeg 480w, images/title_bg@960w.jpeg 960w, 
    images/title_bg@1440w.jpeg 1440w, images/title_bg@1920w.jpeg 1920w">
```

Comment: Note: it appears this just adds the tags as data-* but is still the closest I have come to finding something off-the-shelf. Can easily convert the data- tags again afterwards.